# how to find objects field

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I have Location and I want to retrieve all locations in db by company

I can do this in this way `List<Location> findByCompanyId(Long companyId);`

but How can I retrieve ids of Locations not whole object

```
 List<Long> findByCompanyId(Long companyId);
```

I want the same thing as in first method but without whole object only ids

```
public class Location extends BaseEntity {

@Column(name = "`street_first`", nullable = false)
private String streetFirst;

@Column(name = "`street_second`")
private String streetSecond;

@Column(name = "`city`", nullable = false)
private String city;

@Column(name = "`zip`")
private String zip;

@Column(name = "`state`", nullable = false)
private String state;

@Column(name = "`phone`", nullable = false)
private String phone;

@JoinColumn(name = "`company_id`", nullable = false)
private Company company;
}
//getters and setters
```

Comment: @NicolasLabrot nope he is trying to retrieve two columns and using query annotation. in contrast I am looking for solution which will not use query annotation.

Comment: is there any projection or whatever?

Comment: The related question and your try to achieve the same goal: projection on a N columns  using spring data jpa. Sorry but cf. Robert Niestroj there is no other option than `@Query` annotation

Answer (score 1):

```
@Query("SELECT l.id FROM Location l WHERE l.company.id = :companyId");
List<Long> getLocationIds(@Param("companyId")Long companyId);
```

Comment: Please use @Transactional(readOnly=true) on top of getLocationIds method

Comment: @LovaChittumuri is there any other solution? is it best practice to use Query annotation?

Comment: Yes if u r not using this annotation it will effect on performance issue.